# Segmentation fault (core dumped) on Ubuntu with matrix functions on C++

Tags: c++, matrix, segmentation-fault, dynamic-allocation

I'm trying to build a program in C++ that works a lot with matrices and functions of matrices. My code compiles normally, but when I try to execute it I get the message:

***Segmentation fault (core dumped)***

My code has a lot of function that look like this:

```
void function(double **matrix, ...) {
    //Operations with the matrix
}
```

And I call the functions like this:

```
double **M;
function(M,...);
```

By researching about the message I discovered that I needed to dynamically allocate the matrices that I was going to use, so wrote the following functions that should do this allocation:

```
void allocMatrix(double **M, int nl, int nc) {
M = new double*[nl];
for(int i = 0; i < nl; ++i)
        M[i] = new double[nc];
}

void freeMatrix(double **M, int nl) {
for(int i = 0; i < nl; ++i)
         delete [] M[i];
delete [] M;
}
```

Now with these functions I tried to call my other functions doing the following:

```
double **M;
allocMatrix(M, numberOfLines, numberOfColumns);
function(M,...);
freeMatrix(M, numberOfLines);
```

However, even with this change I keep getting the message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

I even tried to allocate the matrix inside the functions like this:

```
void function(double **matrix, ...) {
    allocMatrix(M, numberOfLines, numberOfColumns);
    //Operations with the matrix
    freeMatrix(M, numberOfLines);
}
```

But it didn't work as well.

Does anyone know where I'm not getting it right?

Comment: C++ is pass-by-value by default.

Comment: an answer to all memory problems: `valgrind`.

Comment: You are better off writing a simple matrix class that is copyable, assignable and swappable (and movable if you have C++11 support). This `**` stuff is quite fragile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `double ***` in the parameter list and send `&M` (the address of `M`) in the call.  Without that, your `M` does not have the matrix and you get the seg fault in a different function.

Answer (score 2):

You're currently passing a copy of `M` to `allocMatrix`.  The memory you allocate here is leaked when the function returns.  You need to pass a pointer to `M` if you want the caller's variable to be modified

```
double **M;
allocMatrix(&M, numberOfLines, numberOfColumns);
function(M,...);
freeMatrix(M, numberOfLines);

void allocMatrix(double ***M, int nl, int nc) {
    *M = new double*[nl];
    for(int i = 0; i < nl; ++i)
            (*M)[i] = new double[nc];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are writing C++, why not use `vector`?

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // This does what your "allocMatrix" does.
    std::vector< std::vector<double> > M(numberOfLines, numberOfColumns);

    // Look Ma!  No need for a "freeMatrix"!
}
```